# Changing the Color of a Heading in resumecls

Tags: color

I recently discovered the [resumecls class](https://ctan.org/pkg/resumecls) and have been using it to build my resume. Currently, I am using Overleaf to edit and work on my resume, and while I enjoy it, I am having issues changing the color of the headings in my resume. [image: The gray headers, who's colors I am trying to change.]

I have found within the [documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/xetex/latex/resumecls/resumecls.pdf) a section showing where the color for the headers are set, but I don't actually know how to change the header color myself. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Editing for clarification: I'm looking for help changing the color of the bar itself, not the text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The color for the headings is called `heading`. So, you can just add somewhere in your preamble (or even in your document if you want to change the color mid-document) `\definecolor{heading}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}` or whatever. Note that the class uses the `color` package, not the newer `xcolor` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document class uses the `color` package (not the newer `xcolor` package) to define the color `heading` that is used for headings. More concretely, it defines

```
\definecolor{heading}{gray}{0.85}
```

Thus, you can simply use this line of code in your preamble or in your document to change the color `heading` to something else:

```
\documentclass{resumecls} 

% change color in whole document
\definecolor{heading}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}

\begin{document}

\heading{foo}

% change color mid-document
\definecolor{heading}{rgb}{1,1,0.5}

\heading{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at other questions related to color for more information about how to define colors in LaTeX.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, for some reason I thought I could do '\definecolor{heading}{colorName}{1,1,.5}'. This solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @thesaltynacl The second argument signifies the color mode, `gray` meaning grayscale.

Comment: I found the [Using Colors in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colors_in_LaTeX) page and am exploring that, I thought gray was a color not a scale.